# merge.zoo removes time zone

Tags: r, merge, timezone, zoo, posixct

The result of `merge.zoo` does not have the same time zone as its input.

Consider the following example

```
library(zoo)
zoo_a=zoo(data.frame(a=1:5),
          seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:01",tz="UTC"),
              as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:05",tz="UTC"),
              by=1)
          )
zoo_b=zoo(data.frame(a=1:4),
          seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:01",tz="UTC"),
              as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:05",tz="UTC"),
              by=1)
          )

zoo_merged=merge(zoo_a,zoo_b)
time(zoo_merged)[1]
#2013-12-31 19:00:01 EST
time(zoo_a)[1]
#2014-01-01 00:00:01 UTC
time(zoo_b)[1]
#2014-01-01 00:00:01 UTC
```

The time zone associated with `zoo_merged` is not really `EST` but

```
library(lubridate)
tz(time(zoo_merged)[1])
#""
```

The time zone attribute seems to have been removed and `R` is probably using some sort of default timezone to display the data.

I can fix this with `lubridate` via

```
time(zoo_merged)=with_tz(time(zoo_merged),tz="UTC")
time(zoo_merged)[1]
#2014-01-01 00:00:01 UTC
```

Is there any way to fix this properly, i.e. without having to change the timezone afterwards?
I was thinking of changing the code for `merge.zoo` but there's not a single line of comments in the respective code...

Comment: I count more than 50 comments in `merge.zoo`. The only way to "fix" this is to submit a feature request to the package maintainer. That said, reconsider what the expected behavior should be. Note that the time is correct. It seems reasonable to me to return the object in your local timezone by default. What should `merge.zoo` do if the objects have different timezones?

Comment: @cryo111 : The reason Joshua sees comments is that he knows how to look at the source. By default comments are not displayed in the byte-compiled listing you get by looking at what appears at the console when you type the function name.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I understand your point with two different time zones. Still, with two identical time zones I would naively have thought that the output has the same tz as the input.

Comment: @BondedDust Right, I have now checked the code and the comments by inspecting the original source code from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html.

Comment: You would not necessarily need to hack the code. Another option would be to just wrap a call to merge.zoo in a function that dresses up your result the way you specify, perhaps with the TZ attribute of the first argument?

Comment: Yes, I have been thinking about that as well. I think I will check whether the time zones of the input are identical and depending on that I will either return a time series with the same tz or a warning message that the tz are different plus the default `merge.zoo` output.

Comment: @cryo111, I can understand your point that two objects with identical timezones should produce a result with that same timezone, but it's not that simple or easy. `zoo` objects can have an index of any class, not just `POSIXct`, so this would have to be special-cased. FWIW, xts does what you expect, but the xts index is always (internally) `POSIXct`, so this is easier to handle.

Comment: A workaround would be: `library(xts); as.zoo(merge(as.xts(zoo_a), as.xts(zoo_b)))`

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks for the hint with `xts`. Haven't thought about the fact that `zoo` can also handle time indexes other than `POSIXct` and that this makes it tricky. Funny, that this very feature was initially the reason why I picked `zoo` and not `xts` as my "standard" time series library.

Comment: BTW: Does anyone of you guys want to turn your suggestions into an answer? Otherwise, I would write it up later this day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution as suggested by G. Grothendieck

```
library(xts)

merge2=function(x,y) {
  as.zoo(merge(as.xts(x), as.xts(y)))
}

time(merge2(zoo_a,zoo_b))[1]
#[1] "2014-01-01 00:00:01 UTC"
```

Or as suggested by 42-

```
merge3=function(x,y) {
  if ((tmp_tzone<-attr(time(x),"tzone"))!=attr(time(y),"tzone")) {
    message("Timezone attributes of x and y are not the same. Using default tz.")
    return(merge(x,y))
  } else {
    tmp=merge(x,y)
    attr(time(tmp),"tzone")=tmp_tzone
    return(tmp)
  }
}

#input with same tzones 
time(merge3(zoo_a,zoo_b))[1]
#[1] "2014-01-01 00:00:01 UTC"

#input with different tzones
zoo_c=zoo(data.frame(a=1:4),
          seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:01",tz="EDT"),
              as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:05",tz="EDT"),
              by=1)
)

time(merge3(zoo_a,zoo_c))[1]
#Timezone attributes of x and y are not the same. Using default tz.
#[1] "2014-01-01 01:00:01 CET"
```