# Why does the time zone attribute get dropped when I add a new series to a zoo object

Tags: r, timezone, zoo

The time zone attribute of my zoo object is stripped when I add a new time series to it.
For example,

```
library(zoo)
ZooObject=zoo(data.frame(a=1:5),
          seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:01",tz="UTC"),
              as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:05",tz="UTC"),
              by=1)
)
attr(time(ZooObject),'tzone')
#"UTC"
ZooObject$b <- 2
attr(time(ZooObject),'tzone')
#NULL
```

The time zone attribute is correctly reported after the zoo object was created, but after the second series was added the time zone was gone (and defaults to the locale).

This was causing me trouble, as I later aggregate hourly data to daily, so retaining the correct time zone matters.
My solution is to keep re-setting the timezone attribute.

```
attr(time(ZooObject),'tzone') <- "UTC"
```

This is similar to [merge.zoo removes time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269425/merge-zoo-removes-time-zone)

Is there a way to stop the time zone from being stripped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to avoid this behavior is to use xts instead of zoo. If you want, you can reclass the object to zoo after your desired transformations.

```
library(xts)
library(zoo)

ZooObject=zoo(data.frame(a=1:5),
              seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:01",tz="UTC"),
                  as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:05",tz="UTC"),
                  by=1)
)

test <- as.xts(ZooObject)

attr(time(test), 'tzone')
#> [1] "UTC"

test$b <- 2
attr(time(test), 'tzone')
#> [1] "UTC"

test2 <- as.zoo(test)
attr(time(test2), 'tzone')
#> [1] "UTC"
```